# React useTransition hook not work properly

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am new to `useTransition` hook in React and I'm not sure how this hook works.

How does the `setState` work inside `useTransition` arrow function?

Here is a piece of sample code for `useTransition`:

```
startTransition(() => {
  console.log("started");
  setResource(fetchProfileData(nextUserId, 2000));
  console.log("end");
});
```

Please have a check this codesandbox link for more detail.
[code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-leftpad-p402qs?file=/src/index.js:531-707)

As I know, there was a optional parameter for useTransition hook for setting timeoutMs, busyDelayMs, and busyMinDurationMs. Is that disappeared?
Here is a sample code for the previous sample code.

```
...
const SUSPENSE_CONFIG = {
  timeoutMs: 4000,
  busyDelayMs: 300,
  busyMinDurationMs: 700,
}
...
const [startTransition, isPending] = React.useTransition(SUSPENSE_CONFIG)
React.useEffect(() => {
    startTransition(() => {
      // Do something for set state here
    })
  }, [stateValue, startTransition])
...
```

Comment: Why do you think is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Overview

`useTransition` is a new feature of React v18.0.

As the [official doc](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#usetransition) says:

> `useTransition` and `startTransition` let you mark some state updates as not urgent. Other state updates are considered urgent by default. React will allow urgent state updates (for example, updating a text input) to interrupt non-urgent state updates (for example, rendering a list of search results).

##### [Syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usetransition)

```js
const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
```

So, once you update state in a transition like this:

```js
startTransition(() => {
  setCount(count + 1);
})
```

it will mark `setCount()` state update as low-priority and only execute it when more urgent state updates (for example, just calling `setCount()` without the transition) are done, and while waiting, `isPending` value will be true.

##### Example

```
function App() {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  function handleClick() {
    startTransition(() => {
      setCount(c => c + 1);
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isPending && <Spinner />}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. You are senior. I have one more question. As I know, there was a optional parameter for setting the transition in the previous React version. For example for timeoutMs, busyDelayMs, and busyMinDurationsMs. Are they disappeared forever? Isn't it possible for integrating those function with the React v18.0?

Comment: Hi @technophyle! I have a question, what can I do if I'd like to set the isPending status as false after 3 seconds? Is it possible?

Comment: @Webdev1025 yes, as of React 18, `useTransition()` does not take any parameter.

Comment: @Cardoso we don't have control over `isPending` because it's read-only, but you can always define a custom state variable and set it to true/false after a few seconds and show content based off of that.