# Can isPending state from useTransition ever become true in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

Looked at [React useTransition hook not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73981685/react-usetransition-hook-not-work-properly) but it didn't address my situation.

I tried to create a Jest to help simulate the situation but it isn't really working

```js
import { expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { renderHook, act, screen, render } from "@testing-library/react-native";
import { useTransition } from "react";
test("useTransition", () => {
  const {
    result,
    rerender,
    unmount,
  } = renderHook(() => useTransition(), {});

  expect(result.current[0]).toBe(false);
  expect(result.current[1]).toBeTruthy();
  const startTransition = result.current[1];
  act(()=> {
    startTransition(()=>{
       // tried to put delays an what not
    });
  })
  // fails on this expectation
  expect(result.current[0]).toBe(true);
});
```

The API contract states that startTransition's parameter needs to be synchronous.

My issue is that I can't seem to get `isPending` to be `true` in React Native.

For context I am trying to build a "TransitionBoundary" like this

```js
import { BlurView } from 'expo-blur';
import { PropsWithChildren, useTransition, createContext, useContext, TransitionStartFunction } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
const TransitionContext = createContext<{ startTransition: TransitionStartFunction }>({
  startTransition: () => { }
})

export const TransitionBoundary = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  console.log(`isPending ${isPending}`)
  return (<TransitionContext.Provider value={{ startTransition }}>
    {children}
    {isPending && (<BlurView style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill} />)}
  </TransitionContext.Provider>)
}
export const useBoundStartTransition = () => useContext(TransitionContext).startTransition;
```

However, as I had noted earlier I can't get the `isPending` value to turn up to be true.

Basically what I want to happen is the example in https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition#usetransition with *The difference between useTransition and regular state updates* that slows down the render by adding a while loop in between, but in React Native it appears to complete that loop while startTransition is being executed as such it does not set the `isPending` state to `true`